# Fitting a table to the text length with the columns closely spaced

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  
% Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  

%% -----------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\fancyhead{}  
\rhead{\thepage}  
\lhead{}  
% Now begin the Appendices, including them as separate files

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}} % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

\appendix % Cue to tell LaTeX that the following 'chapters' are Appendices

\input{Appendices/AppendixA}    

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c c c c c|}
 \hline
 \large{\textbf{Compound Name}} & \large{\textbf{DiscoveRx Gene Symbol}}& \large{\textbf{Entrez Gene Symbol}} & \large{\textbf{Modifier}}&\large{\textbf{Kd (nM)}} \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 Idromonib &AKT1&   AKT1&   $>$ &10000  \\ 
 \hline
 Idromonib &AKT2&   AKT2&   $>$ &10000  \\ 
 \hline
  Idromonib &AKT3&  AKT3&   $>$ &10000  \\ 
 \hline
 Idromonib &ASK1&   MAP3K5  &$>$    &10000\\
  \hline

 \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{MER screen by companyX.\label{MER screen by companyX.}}
  The MER screen demonstrated that of the 39 compounds tested, AB,bc, CD, db and DF had lower Kd values.
\end{table}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}}  % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics
\backmatter

\end{document}
```

I was trying to make this table with 39 rows (in the example code I added 4 rows only, so looks like, even if I make the table sideways, the extra rows may not fit to a single pg), but while `sidewaystable` may look fine, I would prefer it to fit the page vertically, with the columns close together. But what is happening is, as the titles are longer, the columns are spreaded out and the last column is moving out of the margin, What is the best way to make it fit properly within the A4 page in a `\documentclass{article}`?

Comment: again, please provide a test file don't just post a fragment, especially asking how to make a table fit without showing the space that you are fitting it in to is not useful.

Comment: Remark: You may pretty-print code chunks as follows: While editing your posting, highlight the code block and click on the `{}` "button" in the ribbon above the editing window.

Comment: also as noted in your previous questions size commands do not take an argument so `\large{...}` should be `\large ...` without the braces

Comment: Will this be ok?

Comment: No that is completely unusable no one can run the example as you have it now, you are using a local Thesis class we do not have and it will error on `\input{Appendices/AppendixA}`  as we don't have that file. The point of the example code is so that other people can run the document and see the problem and test answers. You should try to demonstrate the issue using a standard class and no input files (see the document in my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multi-line headings

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\hd[1]{\large\bfseries\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
 \begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}|c c c c c|@{}}
 \hline
 \hd{Compound\\Name} & \hd{DiscoveRx\\Gene\\Symbol}& \hd{Entrez\\Gene\\Symbol} & \hd{Modifier}&\hd{Kd\\(nM)} \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 Idromonib &AKT1&   AKT1&   $>$ &10000  \\ 
 \hline
 Idromonib &AKT2&   AKT2&   $>$ &10000  \\ 
 \hline
  Idromonib &AKT3&  AKT3&   $>$ &10000  \\ 
 \hline
 Idromonib &ASK1&   MAP3K5  &$>$    &10000\\
  \hline

 \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{MER screen by companyX.\label{MER screen by companyX.}}
  The MER screen demonstrated that of the 39 compounds tested, AB,bc, CD, db and DF had lower Kd values.
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried this {Compound\\Name} & \hd{DiscoveRx\\Gene\\Symbol}& \hd{Entrez\\Gene\\Symbol} & \hd{Modifier}&\hd{Kd\\(nM)} \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline" before but it was not working without the array package I think?

Comment: it would work without array, it depends how you defined `\hd` @TomalikaUllah