# Creating a latex table and forcing multiple rows for long column header

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I want to create a table with different summary statistics. However, the table is too wide for the page, and therefore not the whole table is displayed. This is because of column headers which are quite long and I try to automatically split the column headers to multiple rows so that the whole table gets displayed within the page.

This would be an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Title of table}
\label{Label}

\begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
\toprule
&  Long column header 1 &  Long column header 2 &  Long column header 3 &  Long column header 4 \\
\midrule
2013 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
2014 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
2015 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
2016 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

    \begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft] 
    \small
    Description of table
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Is there a simple and efficient way to split the long column header into two or three sub rows so that the whole table gets displayed on the page within the text width?

Thanks a lot for your suggestion!

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete document. Page layout ha influence on table appearing, but you not provide any information about it. BTW, instead `tabular` use `tabularx` and its column type ˙X`.

Comment: The text of l,c,r columns are unbreakable of width equal to the content,  but you can use also columns as `p{2cm` or or `p{50pt}`. There are many other options, see the manual of packages `array`, `tabularx` and `tabulary` and for numeric tables also `siunitx`.

Comment: @Zarko thanks a lot for your comment, I added the missing specifications

Comment: see for example `\hd` as defined here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625494/fitting-a-table-to-the-text-length-with-the-columns-closely-spaced/625496#625496

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may easily achieve your formatting objective by replacing the four instances of the `r` column type -- which, as you have (re)discovered, doesn't allow automatic line breaking -- with a centered version of the `p` column type and choosing the widths of the four data columns suitably, say, `2.5cm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}
\usepackage{array} % <-- new
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % <-- new

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Title of table}
\label{Label}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{C{2.5cm}} @{}}
\toprule
&  Long column header 1 &  Long column header 2 
&  Long column header 3 &  Long column header 4 \\
\midrule
2013 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
2014 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
2015 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
2016 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft] 
\small
    Description of table \dots
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks for the great answer and pointing out the changes:)

Answer (score 3):

With `tabularray` package is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Title of table},
  label = {tab:Label},
remark{Note} = {Something noteworthy.},
                ]{colspec={l *{4}{X[c, si={table-format=1.3}]}}
                 }
    \toprule
    &  {{{Long column header 1}}} 
            &  {{{Long column header 2}}} 
                    &  {{{Long column header 3}}} 
                            &  {{{Long column header 4}}} \\
    \midrule
2013 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
2014 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
2015 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
2016 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can observe, in table are used `S` columns incapsulated in `X` column type. Instead of `threeparttable` is used `talltblr` environment defined in the `tabularray` package. For details about this (relatively new) package consult its documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The `makecell` package is your friend for this kind of probleem, with its `\thead` command;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable, booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Title of table}
\label{Label}

\begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
\toprule
& \thead{Long column\\ header 1}& \thead{Long column\\ header 2} & \thead{Long column\\ header 3} & \thead{Long column\\ header 4} \\
\midrule
2013 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
2014 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
2015 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
2016 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

    \begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]
    \small
    Description of table
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Is there a way to get rid of the lines next to the table?

Comment: @fjurt: I guess you mean the vertical lines? I loaded the `showframe` package to make visually obvious that the table did nfit between the margins? . Just delete `\usepackage{showframe}`.